# How to merge multipe spf1 records to one?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, dns-hosting

My question is rather specific than the answers I found. I know a merge record could be something like this:

TXT "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org include:_spf.google.com ~all."

But in my case my spf1 records sometimes have specific names like:

**Mail** TXT "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all." in this the naming mail is included for the other records this is blanc

**Question**

- Do I need to include the name of spf1 record in the merge like 'Mail' (see example)?
- If so How do I do this? Because some spf records have a name and others a blanc.

tnx

Answer (score 0):

All DNS records have a name (even the root records are called '`.`'). Probably the web interface you use strips your domain name from the name of the records (so `your-domain.com.` appears as blanc).

The SPF record that concerns you is the main domain's TXT record (i.e. `your-domain.com.` if you want to protect e-mails from `@your-domain.com`). The names of the included records should be fully qualified names.